# swift 3 local notification: how to change display text for each notification

Tags: notifications, local

I know how to make a local notification that triggers each day at a specific time. But how do I change the UNMutableNotificationContent.Body for each notification?

Now it just display the same text over and over again.

I'm coding for iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = self.notificationTitle // You could set this variable to anything you like
content.body = self.notificationBody // You could set this variable to anything you like
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
```